# How to parse some web page in iOS App?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xcode, parsing

I have a web page, and need to parse content of some div with objective-c.

```
<div id="foo">11</div>
```

Then add it *(11)* to variable.. and then make badge with it.

How to make it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) seems to have a decent introduction and set of tutorials on getting started with scraping in iOS.  I used it a couple of months back as a reference.  It has you use `libxml2` (a C library) and the `hpple` Objective-C library to wrap libxml2 into NSObjects.